# Xamarin Android: Convert PendingResult parameter to SubmitScoreResult

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I'm trying to get a score submitted to Google Play Services Games:

```
var pendingResult=GamesClass.Leaderboards.SubmitScoreImmediate (mGoogleApiClient,leaderboardId,score);
pendingResult.SetResultCallback (this);
```

the operation succeeds and the callback is called:

```
public void OnResult(Java.Lang.Object arg)
{
     var result=arg as Android.Gms.Games.LeaderBoard.ILeaderboardsSubmitScoreResult;
}
```

however result is null, but "arg" contains what seems a valid object.

How can I convert arg into Leaderboards.SubmitScoreResult, which is the object that should appear here according to Play Services Games documentation?

Comment: You are showing `OnResult` but the listener is `OnScoreSubmitted` and that returns two parameters: a StatusCode and a SubmitScoreResult.

Comment: Thanks, that solves half of the problem. So,instead of IResultCallback I have to implement OnScoreSubmittedListener in my listener class. The problem now is that I can't find OnScoreSubmittedListener in the Android.Gms.Games.Leaderboard assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `SubmitScoreImmediate`, you can convert that to use the C#-style async version `SubmitScoreImmediateAsync` and avoid the callback/listener:

```
var result = await GamesClass.Leaderboards.SubmitScoreImmediateAsync(mGoogleApiClient, "StackOverflow", 22747);
var statuses = result.Status;
var scoreSubmissionData = result.ScoreData;
```

Comment: This is weird, I can't find SubmitScoreImmediateAsync either, and I'm using the latest stable Xamarin version of Google Play Services  (42.1001.0) .

Comment: @KakCAT How about `Android.Gms.Games.GamesClass.Leaderboards.SubmitScoreImmediateAsync` Have that? (Just checked `42.1001.0` so you should have it...)

Comment: wow, I don't have that either. I've even checked the .dll with ILSpy just in case Xamarin and VS went mad. It is indeed 42.1001.0 and there's no such function. Is there somewhere an MD5 to know if I'm using the correct Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games.dll ?

Comment: mine is [.....\sln\and_wnb\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games.42.1001.0\lib\MonoAndroid70\]
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games.dll           b8165af74611d9ffd5a60c12e3ed0420

Comment: md5 Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games.42.1001.0/lib/MonoAndroid70/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games.dll
MD5 (Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games.42.1001.0/lib/MonoAndroid70/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games.dll) = `b5fc76a8ebdbb5d7dc068851ce57895c`

Comment: how is this possible? mine came from nuget (as I suppose yours does)

Comment: @KakCAT No idea... and yes from Nuget: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Comment: @KakCAT `SubmitScoreImmediateAsync` is an extension method from  `ILeaderBoardExtensions` in `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Games` assembly....

Comment: Great, that did the trick! :)  I just had to add using Android.Gms.Games.LeaderBoard; for the method to appear. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: NP, still strange the md5 does not match... but happy Xammie coding.... ;-)